# zookeeper check if a particular server is leader

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Using the Zookeeper API, is it possible to know if the current server is the leader of the Zookeeper cluster?

The docs mention **The leader has seen the highest zxid of all the followers.**. Is it possible to check this somehow?

Comment: Why do you want to know if you are connected to the leader?

Comment: no particular reason. i can write my logic in a way that knowing this is not needed. Just wanted to know if it's possible

Comment: You could check [this post on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/601409/command-to-determine-whether-zookeeper-server-is-leader-or-follower)

Answer (score 7):

You can find this information from different locations.
The easiest way is to run from each Zookeeper machine the script `./bin/zkServer.sh status`. You will get an answer of the following form:

> ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
>   Using config: /path/to/conf/zoo.cfg
>   Mode: follower

For the leader node the last line will show that accordingly.

If you want to achieve this from Java code where you have imported the ZK client library you can use the class `FourLetterWordMain` like this:

```
String zkAnswer = FourLetterWordMain.send4LetterWord ("<zk-address>", <zk-port>, "srvr");
```

The answer String will look as follows:

> Zookeeper version: 3.4.10-39d3a4f269333c922ed3db283be479f9deacaa0f, built on 03/23/2017 10:13 GMT
>   Latency min/avg/max: 0/0/6
>   Received: 18893
>   Sent: 18957
>   Connections: 2
>   Outstanding: 0
>   Zxid: 0x280000016d
>   Mode: leader
>   Node count: 337

This code is basically also used by the `zkServer.sh` script.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's explicitly hidden. You could use JMX or one of the four letter words, but that's outside the client API.

Comment: one of the four letter words?

Answer (score 1):

You have to send a stat/srvr 4-letter word to each of the instances and then parse the results. The leader will be the one woth "Mode: Leader". However, this isn't very useful information. The Leader can change at any time. Why do you need this info?